# What is the difference between USB-Mode and HID-Mode?

Tags: usb, hid, token

I have an *Elite EL* token. and I have some tools to work with it. One of the softwares is *Elite EL set mode*. As you see I have two options, HID-Mode and USB-Mode.

**Q : What is the difference?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my expereince, the difference is really only for determining the difference of connection between USB and older Serial and Parallel connections. HID stands for Human Interface Device, if you were wondering. In this mode, the dongle will function as if it is connected to your computer via a Serial port (or other similar olden-days connections), and if it is in USB mode it will function as if the device is connected via USB.

Hope this helped.

Comment: HID mode doesn’t require any additional drivers, though, so it’s preferable in my opinion.

Comment: Dear @DanielB , did you mean if I choose **HID-Mode**, I can work with the token, without installing its driver?

Comment: Yes, that’s right. It’ll probably identify itself as a “Generic HID” device. The USB transceiver for my personal weather station works the same way, without additional drivers or having to run the associated software in admin mode.